# Import error for bootstrap in app.component file

Tags: angular, typescript

I was trying to build a to-do list app,but now I'm having an error while importing the bootstrap.
I can't find a way to solve it.

this is the error

> Error: (SystemJS) platform_browser_dynamic_1.bootstrap is not a function
>       TypeError: platform_browser_dynamic_1.bootstrap is not a function
>   
>       Error loading localhost:3000/app/main.js

app.component.ts

[image: screenshot]

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }  from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
@NgModule({
imports:    [ BrowserModule ],
declarations: [AppComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to import `bootstrap`?. Get rid of that. That's what the error is about. 1) You're not even using it 2) It's outdated

Comment: In the app.component.ts file,I'm using it. You can check it in the screenshot

Comment: Well don't use it. It's outdated. What you have in your `main/app.module` is enough

Comment: I've fixed the error,now its working.